# TouchID for Mobile Web

Tags: touch-id

I had a quick question which after doing a lot of research I still cannot find.

Is it possible for me to create a mobile website that can call on iPhone TouchID, as long as the site is opened in iPhone browser itself, for authentication and login?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know TouchID is for local authentication only. In other words it cannot authenticate any remote action. Also it can only be called with native code within the application itself, not a browser.

However what you can do is to create a UIWebView contains what you intend to display in the application, and call native method to require Touch ID authentication. Then send out HTTP request with the authentication result. Some security issue may occur with this approach, but that is off the topic.